# Replace pattern in specific column in sed

Tags: sed, command-line

I have a tab file with two columns like below

```
BB_12  100_AA
BB_13  101_AB 
BB_14  102_AD
BB_15  103_AC
```

I wish to remove the number_ in second column (replace number_ with nothing). For this I tried sed replace in the following ways unsuccessfully.

```
sed 's/\d+\_//g' infile
sed 's/(\d+\_)//g' infile
```

But none of the tweaks worked. It looks like it is not searching in 2nd column. How to modify this ? The expected output is

```
BB_12  AA
BB_13  AB 
BB_14  AD
BB_15  AC
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sed doesn't support `\d`.. for column related operations, consider using `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just process the last column with **`sed`**:

```
sed -E 's/[^ ]*_([^ ]*) *$/\1/' file
```

The output:

```
BB_12  AA
BB_13  AB
BB_14  AD
BB_15  AC
```

---

**`Awk`** alternative:

```
awk '{ sub(/^[^ ]+_/, "", $2) }1' OFS='\t' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Following simple `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^_]*\)_\(.*\)/\1 \3/g'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
BB_12 AA
BB_13 AB
BB_14 AD
BB_15 AC
```

Comment: The back-references aren't really necessary here, and complicate the expression enormously. Simply replace tab followed by numbers and an underscore with just a tab. `s/ [0-9][0-9]*_/ /`